# When a PayPal subscription payment is successful, why do I see two transactions? One is $0, and the other one is a regular payment

Tags: paypal, subscription

When a PayPal subscription payment is successful, why do I see two transactions? One is $0, and the other one is a regular payment. How does the $0 transaction occur, and how can I remove it?

How does the $0 transaction occur, and how can I remove it?

Comment: Have a look at the names of the transactions. One is to tell you about the new subscriber, the other is the first payment. I misremember the actual names but this is the idea.

Comment: I looked up my IPN code. You get `subscr_signup` to notify you of the new user, and a `subscr_payment` every time they pay. However I found that `subscr_signup` can be received *after* the first `subscr_payment`.

Comment: There are different types of PayPal subscriptions and depending on how they are created there are different things "two transactions" can mean, so this question needs more specifics if it is to be answered with any precision